# Message Expiry for pulsar messages

Tags: apache-pulsar

How to get the expiry date for particular message in pulsar by using Pulsar admin API ( or ) is there any way to findout whether particular message is expired or not ?

Answer (score 2):

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/cookbooks-retention-expiry/

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/admin-api-overview/

That can help, otherwise join the slack.   There is very fast response to most questions.

Slack
There is a Pulsar slack channel that is used for informal discussions for devs and users.

The Slack instance is at https://apache-pulsar.slack.com/

You can self-register at https://apache-pulsar.herokuapp.com/